# typescript error for cypress custom commands

Tags: typescript, cypress

I setup typescript for cypress

and try to setup as a [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Install-TypeScript),

But I cannot solve one ts error (`TS2345: Argument of type '(value: string) => Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>' is not assignable to parameter of 'CommandFn<"dataCy">'.`)

what is this error meaning?

[image]

#### tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "types": ["cypress", "node", "./support"]
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

#### cypress/support/commands.ts

```js
export {};
/**
 * @see https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Configure-tsconfig-json
 */
Cypress.Commands.add("dataCy", (value: string) => {
  return cy.get(`[data-cy=${value}]`);
});
```

#### cypress/support/index.d.ts

(Reference this [blog](https://medium.com/@gghalistan/adding-custom-commands-to-cypress-typescript-28d23f90c2fd))

```js
export {};

declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      /**
       * Custom command to select DOM element by data-cy attribute.
       * @example cy.dataCy('greeting')
       */
      dataCy(value: string): Chainable<Element>;
    }
  }
}
```

#### cypress/e2e/add-todo-test.cy.ts

```js
export {};

describe("Add New TodoItem", () => {
  it("find new added item", () => {
    cy.visit("http://localhost:3000");
    cy.dataCy("input-text").focus().type("Review Pull Request");
    cy.dataCy("add-new-btn").click();
    cy.dataCy("todo-list").contains("Review Pull Request");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

From my test, this error is due solely to the return type you gave in the `index.d.ts`

You have

```js
dataCy(value: string): Chainable<Element>
```

but it should be

```js
dataCy(value: string): Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>
```

This is because Cypress commands return a `Chainable` object wrapping a `JQuery` object, which wraps zero, one, or many element that were found by the custom command.

Everything else is working, but I generally use a more specific entry in `tsconfig.json` (presuming you have an extension tsconfig in the `/cypress` folder).

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types": ["cypress", "node", "./support/index.d.ts"]
  },
  ...
}
```

If you only have `tsconfig.json` at the project root, then the entry should be

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types": ["cypress", "node", "./cypress/support/index.d.ts"]
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the `Cypress.Commands.add()` function should return void. You can omit the return statement and this will work, but not as you might expect. The command will not allow you to simply write a query like this (although you could query and click something with the command). Instead you should use `Cypress.Commands.addQuery()`.

Try this:

commands.ts...

```
Cypress.Commands.addQuery("getDataCy", function outer_func(value:string) {
  const getFn = cy.now("get", `[data-cy="${value}"`) as () => Promise<HTMLElement>;
  const inner_func = () => {
    return getFn();
  };
  return inner_func;
});
```

index.d.ts...

```
export {}
declare global {
   namespace Cypress {
       interface Chainable {
           getDataCy(value:string): Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>;
       }
   }
}
```

As to why this is the case, I am sure a more seasoned user could give a better answer. Or you may be inclined to read into the docs to get a better answer. I hope this helps though I am a few months late.